# How to interpret the declaration of the following function

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

```
export declare abstract class AbstractBootstrapConsole<A extends INestApplicationContext, O extends CommonBootstrapConsoleOptions = CommonBootstrapConsoleOptions> {
    protected service: ConsoleService;
    protected container: A;
    protected readonly options: O;
    constructor(options: O);
    protected useDecorators(): this;
    init(): Promise<A>;
    getService(): ConsoleService;
    getOptions(): O;
    boot(argv?: string[]):     
    Promise<CommandResponse>;
    abstract create(): Promise<A>;
}
```

I am trying to understand this <strike>function</strike> class declaration. It is a part of nestjs-console module.
I am having trouble understanding the declaration. What does

```
class A<B extends C, D extends E = F>
```

mean? In the future, how would I go about looking this up on my own? I can't find this in the documentation for Typescript.

Update: Got some very clear answers! Thank you all!

Comment: This is not a function declaration, its a class declaration. Not trying to nit-pick here, just personally I spend a few seconds looking through the class declaration to figure out which method/function is your question about, until I realized its about the generic declaration of the class itself.

Anyways [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#example) from the official docs should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called generics.

```
class A<B extends C, D extends E = F>
```

You are defining a class called A, which accepts two generic parameters, called B and D. B must extend interface C, D must extend interface E. And if generic parameter D is not provided, it defaults to the interface F.

```
interface C {
    name: string;
}

interface E {
    something: number;
}

interface F extends E {
    somethingElse: boolean;
}

class A<B extends C, D extends E = F> {
    constructor(b: B, d: D) {

    }
}

interface D extends C {
    surname: string;
}

const a: A<D> = {}; // Optional generic parameter default to F, constuctor parameter d must be of type F.
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down into its own individual parts.

```js
class Foo<T>
```

this means that `Foo` is a class that takes a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameter `T`, nothing particularly special about this. When you create an instance of `Foo`, you'll need to provide a concrete `T`.

```js
class Foo<T extends U>
```

what we've added here is a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) on the generic type parameter `T`.
You can read this as `T must be assignable to U`.

A more practical example could be something like

```js
class Foo<T extends any[]>
```

in which we are saying that `T` must be an array.

The final bit is

```js
class Foo<T = U>
```

which simply provides a default type parameter in case `T` is not specified when creating an instance of `Foo`.